Spring Data JPA findById, Part 2
My application fails because my ticket repository is null
Spring Data JPA findById, Part 2
You can reference my project at: (https://github.com/andre1011green/PracticeProject2.git) with the following edits below
When I run my app I get the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories.TicketRepository.findAllByEmployeeID(int)" because "ticketRepository" is null
at com.Practice.PracticeProject.Service.Login.AllMyTickets(Login.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
 public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id, TicketRepository ticketRepository )
    {

        List<Tickets> myTickets = ticketRepository.findAllByEmployeeID(id);  ==> Here is the line of code this is breaking: 
        if(myTickets.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Did not find any Tickets for given empoyeeid");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return myTickets;
    }

}

Why am I getting a null pointer exception?
Here is the login class:

package com.Practice.PracticeProject.Service;

import com.Practice.PracticeProject.Model.Tickets;
import com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories.TicketRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class Login
{
    Authentication currentUser;

    public Login() { }

    public Login(Authentication currentUser)
    {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public String loggInUser(Principal principal, UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());

        if (userDetails != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Andre the current user is " + userDetails.getUsername());
            return userDetails.getUsername();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No current user");
            return "No Current User";
        }

    }




    public String currentUserInfo(Principal principal, UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(principal.getName());
        if (userDetails != null)
        {
            return userDetails.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Current User";
        }
    }

    public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id, TicketRepository ticketRepository  )
    {
        List<Tickets> myTickets = ticketRepository.findAllByEmployeeID(id);
        if(myTickets.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Did not find any Tickets for given empoyeeid");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return myTickets;
    }

}


Here is the repository class:

package com.Practice.PracticeProject.Repositories;

import com.Practice.PracticeProject.Model.Tickets;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Tickets, Integer>
{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,  value = "SELECT * FROM tickets  WHERE ticketid = :ticketid")
    List<Tickets> findAllByEmployeeID(@Param("ticketid") int ticketid);
}


Thanks
I am expecting my application to return a list of tickets via Spring JPA, I have tried various ways to inject TicketsRepository  but I always get a null pointer exception at runtime. This is the same project from my previous post with the new edits posted here.

Your controller has a TicketRepository injected, so your method should be public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id)

This method is already public

public List AllMyTickets(int id)

I made the following changes and my code worked, now returning a list of tickets
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Tickets, Integer>
{
  @Query(nativeQuery = true,  value = "SELECT * FROM tickets  WHERE employeeid = :employeeid")
  List<Tickets> findAllByEmployeeID(@Param("employeeid") int employeeid);
    
}


@Controller
public class UserController
{
   ...

    @Autowired
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    public UserController(TicketRepository ticketRepository)
    {
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
    }


    ...

    @GetMapping("/displayMyTickets")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Tickets> displayMyTickets(Login mylogin)
    {

        this.mylogin = mylogin;
        int id = 1;
        return mylogin.AllMyTickets(id, ticketRepository);
    }
}


@Service
public class Login
{
   @Autowired
   TicketRepository ticketRepository;

   ...

    public List<Tickets> AllMyTickets(int id, TicketRepository ticketRepository)
    {
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
        List<Tickets> myTickets = ticketRepository.findAllByEmployeeID(id);
        if(myTickets.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Did not find any Tickets for given empoyeeid");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return myTickets;
    }

